# How to use Zend_Form in a layout script

Tags: zend-framework, forms

I am using Zend Framework, I have a layout.phtml which renders navigation.phtml. How can I display a search form in this script?

Where is the right place to set the form? In normal view scripts I will use the controllerAction to set the form, and simply echo it.

Do I need an FrontController Plugin, which sets the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup the form in a file called MyForm.php where you write a form class that extends Zend_Form

```
class SearchForm extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
        //setup your form
    }
}
```

In your controller you instantiate the form and pass it to the view

```
$form = new SearchForm();
$this->view->form = $form;
```

And in your .phtml you echo it

```
<?php echo $this->form; ?>
```

Comment: thanks, but me question is : how to setup the form in an layout script (displayed an every page)